# Plotting fractions using `bquote(frac( .(number), .(number)) )` in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, expression

I'm trying to plot fractions inside a `geom_tex(label = )` using the `bquote(frac( .(number), .(number)) )` syntax.

But it seems ggplot2 doesn't recognize this. Is there a way to plot these fractions correctly?

Reproducible data and code plus what I tried:

```
set.seed(0)
DATA <- data.frame(
  x=sample(0:1,50,T),
  y=sample(LETTERS[1:2],50,T))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(DATA)+aes(x=x,y=after_stat(count)/ sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL == x])))+
  geom_bar() +
  
# Problem starts with `label =`:
  geom_text(aes(y = after_stat(count)/ sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL==x])),
            label = bquote(frac(.(after_stat(count)), .(sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL==x])))))),
            vjust = -.1, color = "black", size = 2, stat = "count") +
  
  facet_grid(vars(y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create your plotmath expression as a character string and use `parse=TRUE` in `geom_text`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.3.1

ggplot(DATA) +
  aes(x = x, y = after_stat(count) / sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL == x]))) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      y = after_stat(count) / sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL == x])),
      label = after_stat(
        paste0(
          "frac(", count, ", ",
          sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL == x])), ")"
        )
      )
    ),
    vjust = -.1, color = "black", size = 2, stat = "count", 
    parse = TRUE
  ) +
  facet_grid(vars(y))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Although I wish there was a way for the numerator and the denominator to be closer to the faction line. Right now, they are so far away from the fraction line that if a bar is closer to 60% the numerator won't show.

Comment: Yeah. Would be nice if the panel size would adjust to accommodate for that. But of course could increase the expansion of the scale, e.g. try `scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0, .1))` to make room for the labels.

Comment: Just curious, can we actually the `count` that ggplot is using from the whole ggplot object?